# Count documents and total sum of their array property, grouped by multiple properties of a subdocument

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Having N documents of the following type:

```
{
    "source": {
        "domain": "1",
        "type": "2"
    },
    "assets": [1, 2]
}
{
    "source": {
        "domain": "3",
        "type": "4"
    },
    "assets": [3, 4, 5]
}
```

How can I get a total count of assets among all documents, grouped by domain + type?

In the above case, a query should return that domain:1 + type:2 has 2 combined assets in 1 document, while domain3 + type:4 has 3 combined assets in 1 document.

Note that `domain:1 + type:2 != domain:2 + type:1`.

My first attempt was

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "arraySize":{"$size":"$assets"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
        "_id": {"$concat": ["$source.domain", "-", "$source.type"]},
        "totalArraysSize":{"$sum":"$arraySize"}
        }
    },
])
```

But it only returns `[{'_id': None, 'totalArraysSize': 616}]`, with no grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write up a solution after experimenting with the syntax:

```
collection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {"source": "$source.domain", "type": "$source.type"},
        "asset_count":{"$sum":{"$size":"$assets"}},
        "total_count":{"$sum": 1},
    }
}])
```